# How to instantiate golang struct by name and use it as that type without directly referencing the struct

Tags: go

I've seen a very similar question to this one but it doesn't address one important detail.  How do you do this entirely through variables and without directly referencing the struct.

For instance, given the following, I've tried a few variants of `main()` methods to test this out:

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
)

type Operable interface {
    compute() string
}

type Operator struct {
    Operable
    Name string
    Type string
}

func (o Operator) compute() string {
    return "operating"
}

type Read struct {
    Operator
}

func (r Read) compute() string {
    return "reading"
}

var Operators = make(map[string]reflect.Type)

func init() {
    Operators[reflect.TypeOf(Read{}).Name()] = reflect.TypeOf(Read{})
}
```

I want to instantiate a new `Read struct` (`Operator`) from a string.
In the following, I get the error `theOp.Name undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)`.  Which is expected.

```
func main() {
    nameOfOp := "Read"
    typeOfOp := Operators[nameOfOp]

    theOp := reflect.New(typeOfOp).Elem().Interface()

    fmt.Println(theOp.Name)
}
```

If I do the following, I get the error `typeOfOp is not a type`.

```
func main() {
    nameOfOp := "Read"
    typeOfOp := Operators[nameOfOp]

    theOp := reflect.New(typeOfOp).Elem().Interface().(typeOfOp)

    fmt.Println(theOp.Name)
}
```

The only thing I have found to compile is to explicitly enter the struct type.  But I want this to be dynamic, any thoughts?

```
func main() {
    nameOfOp := "Read"
    typeOfOp := Operators[nameOfOp]

    theOp := reflect.New(typeOfOp).Elem().Interface().(Read)

    fmt.Println(theOp.Name)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not cast them to the Operable interface instead?

Comment: @JimDeville I've tried that but then I can't access the field `Name` and I get the error `theOp.Name undefined (type Operable has no field or method Name)`

Comment: Is that a field you could expect everywhere? Could you wrap it with a method in Operable?

Comment: that's a good idea.  The only issue is that there will be other attributes that will be different, but I'm thinking that I might just be approaching this in an anti-Go way.

Comment: The way I would approach it if I needed that kind of control is a type switch: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch